# Why are my UV coordinates distorted?

Tags: modeling, uv

When unwrapping a seamed object, my UV coordinates come out very weird. Whereas several sections have equal area on the model, they come out distorted when projected to the UV mappings:

[image: model with the uv mapping side-by-side]

closer view of the UV map:

[image: closer view of the uv map]

I already tried applying the object's scale (Ctrl+A, Scale). It did help, but the UV is *still* distorted a bit. Is that normal, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

.blend file [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/34355) (the model in question is in the 4th layer)

Comment: What method of unwrapping did you use? Although it is common to edit UV's manually, it shouldn't come out this bad. Try *Project From View* when in side view.

Comment: I used just the Unwrap, as I wanted to use the seams I had created. I can _Project From View_ that ring, but can't do that with the cylinder as it will never capture all of it. Also, with _Cylinder Projection_, the texture will be distorted to fit the UV projection, so I can't just put something like a decal and expect it to follow the model, can I?

Comment: Something like *Shrinkwrap*?

Comment: Um yea, that sounds right.

Comment: There is a modifier called the *Shrinkwrap* modifier, you add it to the decal and then select the target mesh. You can edit the offset and a few other things. Add a sub-div modifier right before it on simple just to give more vertices for it to work with.

Comment: really weird angles. Try to unwrap the complete object in 1 time, not small zones. Check if you have an addon messing you UVs (search something like UV in addon list)

Comment: That's what I diz, I unwrapped the whole OBJ at once

Comment: can you upload the .blend ?

Comment: Sure, I'l do it later when I'm on the PC again

Comment: @wingleader it is unwrapped correctly !

Comment: It unwraps perfectly for me.  I didn't change anything, I just opened the file, selected the ring and pressed 'u->Unwrap'.  The ring comes out completely symmetrical with no visible distortion.  This now brings up the question: What are you doing differently and why is it not working for you?

Comment: Oh... I really thought there was a way for it to be kinda straighter without editing it individually. Well, so my question has no answer?

Comment: if you need it to be a circle remove the edge seam that is cutting it

Comment: Which version do you use? When I unwrap the ring a segment is missing. But in orthographic mode I can force a complete undistorted unwrap using *project from view*.

Comment: opened it, checked your UV then unwrapped with U : all fine. Tried the face loop alone : all fine. Tried with modifiers on : all fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by the modifiers added to the mesh.

In Orthographic mode <kbd>Numpad-5</kbd>,  Back view <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad-1</kbd>.
You can unwrap it with <kbd>U</kbd> *Unwrap from View* without the distortion:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, finally i found out that it was the UV Unwrap Method (Previously called  "**Edit Mode > Find the UV calculation options**")

In current version after you Unwrap your model you can find it on Tools Panel and its called Method. After changing it from **Angle Based** to **Conformal** I have straight edges in my UV map (previously edges were distorded).

[image]